# Build child module before parent module execute

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin, parent-pom

In my project structure I have 2 child project module which creates the tar file once build(Not using assembly to build child module, using ant plugin). Now I have a parent module which copy child modules tar file into another tar created though assembly plugin as part of release structure.

Parent pom Assembly

```
<execution>
    <id>make-assembly</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

Assembly file:

```
<fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/module1/target</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/install/bin</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.tar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
```

Now as parent build executing before child module build, parent module going to assembly file and assembly file trying to fetch file name mentioned but as child module not build till then so, giving error. But if I build the child project manually then it's working fine.

So, how I can instruct to build the child module first or any other solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the assembly in the parent, but add another module, e.g. named "release", which has the other two modules as a dependency. Thus, Maven will first build the two modules and create the tar-files, and then the release-module will assemble everything together.